# Block all websites in Windows 8, except for 3

Tags: windows-8, blocking, hosts-file

I would like to create a whitelist of 3 websites on a Windows 8 machine. All other websites would be blocked. This environment is not managed by a server, these will be just 2 independent boxes.

One solution I thought of is the hosts file. Is there a way to use wildcards in the hosts file? I played around with this and couldn't get that working.

I only need an amateur solution to this problem -- it only needs to prevent basic internet use. The users of these machines (children) are not tech-savvy, and do not know how to use proxies, etc. to get around rules. For example, even if your solution only works on IE, that is fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The normal Windows `hosts` file doesn't support wildcard entries.

You can use **[AcrylicDNS](http://mayakron.altervista.org/wikibase/show.php?id=AcrylicHome)** and point your DNS settings to `127.0.0.1`. You can then edit the `AcrylicHosts.txt` file with wildcard entries.

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested only in IE, have you looked at Content Advisor?  http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/using-content-advisor-block-inappropriate-content

In general:

1. Enable the Content Advisor in Internet Settings
2. Create an override password for your own use
3. Set each category to None using the sliders
4. Disallow access to sites with no rating
5. Add your exceptions to the Approved Sites list

Answer (score 0):

**Family safety** is a new feature introduced in windows 8 which will help us to control almost everything in our PC

**- Web Filtering**

**- Time Limits**

**- Windows store and game restrictions**

**- App Restrictions**

if you want more details about this feature you can visit on my blog. if you want the link comment here

Comment: http://feelsecured.wordpress.com/2013/11/21/family-safety-a-new-feature-in-windows-8/